# Why don't we have underground thermal power plants?

Tags: estimation, power

I learned from wikipedia that for the production of electricity, the temperature of geothermal sources must be at least 150 degrees Celsius.

Also wiki says that at a depth of 6 kilometers, the temperature of the earth is about 270 degrees Celsius, that is more than enough to generate electricity. And this heat is not exhausted, because it comes from the core of the earth. So this energy can be called conditionally "infinite".

Why do we not have underground thermal power plants all over the world?

We have robots, rovers, drones and we know how to extract minerals... And also we can send robots to Mars! But here you need only 6 kilometers underground.

We can dig a separate hole in each area, 6 km deep, and have local free energy forever, or at least hundreds of years ahead.
Why doesn't anyone do this?

Comment: Often the reason we don't actually do things that physics says are possible is economic: It costs more than the benefit gained, or it costs more than alternative solution. Finding the most economical solution is engineering, not physics.

Comment: That said, you might need to read your sources more carefully (or they are not worded precisely). It's likely not that you need a source that's 150 C. More likely you need a temperature difference of somewhere around 125 C between the source and whatever forms the cold side of your heat engine. So working at 6 km depth where everything is 270 C may not solve the problem.

Comment: @ThePhoton your above comment, **is flawless**. this is too true; (No sarcasm, i mean it) :) thanks for setting that comment! +1

Comment: It also isn't "just 6km" down. 6km through solid rock with pressure bearing down on all you from all sides can't be compared it with a 6km walk in the park horizontally on the surface of the Earth. Compare to climbing Mount Everest which isn't through solid rock. Or compare to water which is less dense than rock. Crush depth of a nuclear submarine is 400m.

Comment: You don't need a high temperature to run a heat engine, you need a significant temperature _difference_ between a heat source and a heat sink. It's plenty hot deep underground, but you also need access to something that's plenty cold in order to run the engine. That's why big thermal power stations either are located next to large bodies of water or, have enormous hyperboloid cooling towers on site.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm confused about where the pressure comes from that you're talking about - wouldn't the rock be solid at only 270C? There are mines which are ~4km deep, and though the air pressure is higher, the walls themselves aren't exerting pressure from all sides.

Comment: @SusanW No material is truly rigid not even solid homogenous block of material and the Earth's crust is definitely not that.

Comment: @DKNguyen sorry, still confused - if you are at the bottom of a deep mine, the drilled rock once stabilized doesn't come out and crush you, does it? Or are you talking about some kind of gradual creepage over years?

Comment: @SusanW Both. I'm fairly certain you can't just assume the drilled rock is stabilized.  The walls of a vertical hole are subject to buckling and can cave in on themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The *physics* reason is that energy isn't generated directly from heat.  It's generated from heat reservoirs that are different in *temperature**.  So if you dig a 6km deep hole and lower a thermal engine down into it, you now have to transport heat *from* your thermal engine *to* the surface to cool it.

The *practical* reason is that since you need the piping anyway, you may as well just have a heat exchanger down there.

The *economic* reason is that a 6km deep hole that's big enough, and the requisite insulated pipes and whatnot, costs a lot of money.  In order to be economically feasible you need to earn your money back before the plant wears out.  In order to be environmentally beneficial, you need to "earn back" whatever environmental damage you caused digging the hole and building the plant, again, before it all wears out.

* This is basic thermodynamics.  Try searching on "thermodynamics", "heat engine", or "Carnot cycle".

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that the most efficient way to get heat out of the depths and up to the surface is if the borehole is *wet*- that is, there's an *aquifer* down deep that is heated by the geothermal heat flux. then all you have to do is drill a well down into the layer of hot water and the pressure at that depth pushes the hot water to the surface, where you can use it to give up its heat to a heat exchanger containing the water you boil into steam to drive your turbines. This extra step is needed because the geothermal water is loaded with dissolved minerals that would otherwise foul the turbines.

This means that the borehole is going to be *shallow* (~hundreds of feet instead of ~thousands of feet) because there's no water ~6 kilometers down and for the water to be hot enough to use, there must be a *local* heat source down there- in the form of a mass of volcanic rock left over from some earlier eruption or magma movement in the past, which hasn't finished cooling off yet and is still super hot.

These thing occur naturally- like in Yellowstone Park, where the hot volcanic rock sits right under an aquifer full of water that the hot rock can get hot enough to create a steam explosion, yielding a dramatic thing called a *geyser* along with boiling mud pools and ponds full of water hot enough to kill you if you fell in.

There is one such *geothermal field* in California near the town of Calistoga where there are small geysers and hot springs. The local power company drilled into the hot (wet) rock and has been running turbines off that hot water for decades, but the overall operation is small and by now so much of the heat has already been extracted  that their power output is beginning to decline.